# Have a problem while using pipenv shell command to acttivate virtual enviroment

Tags: python, environment-variables, pipenv

I just have short question regarding environment variables. I am experiencing a problem with the `pipenv shell` command while trying to activate a virtual environment. I read [the documentation](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#about-shell-configuration), which says

> If you experience issues with `$ pipenv shell`, just check the `PIPENV_SHELL` environment variable, which `$ pipenv shell` will use if available.

How can I implement the above mentioned instructions (please explain in detail)? I tried to set the environment variable named `PIPENV_SHELL` to the path of the virtual env but didn't succeed.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't succeed"? What happened, versus what did you expect to happen? Please provide the command you ran to try to set the `PIPENV_SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: Is [this](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#about-shell-configuration) the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: Yeah, that is right

Comment: I'm not sure if that documentation is official documentation, since it looks like it is from a fork of the official `pipenv` project.

Comment: I created env. var named PIPENV_SHELL and set its value to the path in which virtual environment is.

Comment: I did it through "edit system env. var" (I use Windows10)